# How to use find_in_set() function in mysql to filter a data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem in my query.
Here's my video table structure list

```
+----+----------+---------------+
| id | category | subcategory   |
+----+----------+---------------+
| 91 |        1 | 1,3,6,8,10,14 |
| 90 |        1 | 1,7,8,9,10    |
| 89 |        1 | 1,6,8         |
| 88 |        1 | 1,7,8,9,10    |
| 87 |        1 |               |
| 86 |        1 | 1,6,8,10,11   |
| 84 |        2 | 2,11,13       |
| 83 |        1 | 1,8,10,11     |
| 82 |        3 | 3             |
| 81 |        1 | 1,6,7,9,10    |
+----+----------+---------------+
```

Now I want to select only the videos within a specific category and if the video has the same category it should display also.

My query goes like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM video_details 
WHERE display_active='1' 
OR category IN (3) 
AND (FIND_IN_SET("3",subcategory)) 
ORDER BY actress 
DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

And its output is like this:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 89 |
| 88 |
| 86 |
| 84 |
| 82 |
| 81 |
| 80 |
| 79 |
| 78 |
| 77 |
| 76 |
| 75 |
| 74 |
| 73 |
| 72 |
+----+
```

As you can see video ID 89 doesn't have the category of 3 in the subcategory column and also the others.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: I don't get it. How can I implement that kind of query?

Comment: The video id can be selected by using category and subcategory. But the main filter is the category column. And if the video doesn't have the exact category filter it will look on the subcategory if it is exist. Did I get your question?

Comment: The reason I used `OR category IN (3)` because sometimes it can be like this `OR category IN (1,14)`

Answer (score 0):

when you use

```
display_active='1' 
OR category IN (3) 
AND (FIND_IN_SET("3",subcategory))
```

it means the rows that display_active='1' AND (FIND_IN_SET("3",subcategory)) will output or category IN (3) will output. so ID 89 shows. if i get you right i guess you need this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM video_details 
WHERE display_active='1' 
OR ( category IN (3) 
  AND (FIND_IN_SET("3",subcategory)) )
ORDER BY actress 
DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```